# How do i use a list that is made in another file

Tags: python, list, combobox, sqlite, pyqt5

Hello i am trying to get a variable out of another file but i don't know what i am doing wrong.

This is the first file. I am trying to take values from a list that is made in the second file and put them into a combobox but i don't know how to return the list to the first file. I tried the return statement thing but it tells me there should be none

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLabel, 
QComboBox, QApplication)
import selectColumn


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        ItemList=selectColumn.Column()
        print(ItemList)
        self.lbl = QLabel("1", self)
        combo = QComboBox(self)
        for i in range(len(ItemList)):
            Item=ItemList[i]
            combo.addItem(Item)


        combo.move(50, 50)
        self.lbl.move(50, 150)

        combo.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated)        

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('QComboBox')
        self.show()


    def onActivated(self, text):

        self.lbl.setText(text)
        self.lbl.adjustSize()  


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is the second file. This is the file that makes the column values into a list.

```
import sqlite3
class Column(object):
    def __init__(self):
        db= sqlite3.connect("SQLite database")

        cursor = db.cursor()

        cursor.execute("""SELECT Item_ID FROM Items_Table""")
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        print(data)

        db.commit()
        cursor.close()
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second file, `selectColumn.py`, you define class `Column`. Its `__init__()` method performs a select query on the database and retrieves all rows which it stores in the variable `data`. At the end of the method `data` goes out of scope and is deleted. Therefore you can not retrieve it again later, it is lost.

What you need to do is assign the results of the query to a *member* (or attribute) of the object. To do this use `self.data = cursor.fetchall()`. Now you can access `data` through a instance of the `Column` class.

```
import sqlite3

class Column(object):
    def __init__(self):
        with sqlite3.connect("SQLite database") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()    
            cursor.execute("""SELECT Item_ID FROM Items_Table""")
            self.data = [item[0] for item in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Notice that I have changed the code to use a context manager when opening the database. This is a little cleaner as you don't need to worry about closing the cursor or database connection.

Also, `cursor.fetchall()` will return a list of tuples. Each tuple contains a single element, item ID. It will be more convenient to users of this class to have a list of just the IDs without the tuple wrapper. To do that I have used a list comprehension to extract the first (and only) element of each tuple. This results in a list of IDs.

Now, in the first file you can do this:

```
column = selectColumn.Column()
...
for item_id in column.data:
    combo.addItem(item_id)
```

Comment: i have tried it but is tells me there is an unexpected tuple

Comment: @S.Lindqvist: where is that error coming from? Can you post the traceback for it? If it is happening at `combo.addItem(Item)`, that should work because my code adds strings to the combo, not tuples.

Answer (score 0):

It will be a simpler design if you remove the class Column in the second file. As you have shown a function can solve your problem.

```
import sqlite3
def getData():
  db = sqlite3.connect("SQLite database")
  cursor = db.cursor()
  cursor.execute("""SELECT Item_ID FROM Items_Table""")
  data = cursor.fetchall()
  db.close()
  return data
```

And, in the first file, change the line `ItemList=selectColumn.Column()` by `itensIds = selectColumn.getData()`

Comment: i tried both solution. however, they both come up with the same error. Unexpected tuple